# Replacing files throws UnauthorizedAccessException in WinRT / Win8

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Every once in a while, StorageFiles get locked and I get an UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to overwrite them. I cannot replicate this, it only happens randomly. This is the code for creating files:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // ...populate stream with serialized data...

    StorageFile file;
    Stream fileStream;

    try
    {
        file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Access denied on file {0}", fileName);
        return;
    }

    fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

    using (fileStream)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        await fileStream.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

Once a file starts throwing UnauthorizedAccessException, it will always throw it. As if the system has the file locked and I cannot touch it. I have to uninstall the application and rebuild.

When I open the file in my document, I can see that data there. Everything is fine. It was written successfully.

Can anyone see a problem with my code?

Comment: Same effect in my app on Windows 8.1. Replacing a file fails randomly.

Comment: Same situation here. One think I found while sifting through the data is that this does not affect every device. Across my userbase, this error happens only on 3-5 percent of devices.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saving the file token in the future access list? I ran into this problem when loading files and trying to save updates later. Once I started using the future access list, the problems went away.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemaccesslist

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case when the same file is being accessed from two different points in the code at the same time.